# Text formatting in Yaml "example:"

Tags: yaml, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm trying to display some formatted text in a YAML file (in the `example:` key):

```
  log_level_per_component:
     type: object
     example:
       "{
        \"Component1\": \"Info\",\n
        \"Component2\": \"Debug\",\n
        \"Component3\": \"Fatal\",\n
        ...\n
        }"
```

for getting such a Swagger output:

```
"log_level_per_component": "{
                            "Component1": "Info",n
                            "Component2": "Debug",n
                            "Component3": "Fatal",n
                            ...
                            }"
```

but I always get this:

```
"log_level_per_component": "{ \"Component1\": \"Info\",\n \"Component2\": 
\"Debug\",\n \"Component3\": \"Fatal\",\n ...\n }"
```

Any idea what I can do to fix it?

Update 2018-05-17 for Helen's screenshot request about her solution:

This is what I get with both solutions by using "example:":
[image]

And this what I get by using "examples:":
[image]

Both are always empty.

Answer (score 0):

YAML is a superset of JSON, so you can use the normal JSON object literal syntax in YAML:

```yaml
  log_level_per_component:
    type: object
    example:
      {
       "Component1": "Info",
       "Component2": "Debug",
       "Component3": "Fatal"
      }
```

Alternatively, you can use YAML object syntax, and Swagger UI will render the example as JSON (provided that your request or response type is JSON):

```yaml
  log_level_per_component:
    type: object
    example:
      Component1: Info
      Component2: Debug
      Component3: Fatal
```

Comment: Hi!! Yes, the request type is JSON. I tried with both options and I get now:
`log_level_per_component": {}`

Something missing? :-O

Comment: @neo where are you seeing that result - in Swagger Editor, Swagger UI, etc.? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @neo it works fine for me in the latest Swagger UI/Editor: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxCUf.png. Please make sure the indentation is correct. Paste your spec into http://editor.swagger.io to check for syntax errors. If it still does not work, please edit your question and post the complete spec.

Comment: you are right, in the editor.swagger.io it works fine. I saw now that our converter from YAML files to one global Swagger file is removing this.

In the YAML:
`example: { "Component1": "Info", "Component2": "Debug", "Component3": "Error" }`

In the Swagger file:
`example: ""`

I will check why and I will let you know.